# The soap services is working in SOAPUI but its not working in mule soft web services consumer

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, soapui

I have web service wsdl file and its loaded successfully in SOAPUI. This is an request method.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org  /soap/envelope/" xmlns:asi="http://siebel.com/asi/">
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <asi:VSPOSCSyncRealTimeQueryById>
        <PrimaryRowId>1-test</PrimaryRowId>
     </asi:VSPOSCSyncRealTimeQueryById>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This above method is an working fine in SOAPUI. But when I try
to implement in mulesoft using web service consumer then the method is not populating.

This is an screen shot .
[image]

The above picture showing that the mule soft web service consumer is populating the only parameter without operation name but SOAPUI is populating both operation and parameter and its working. so any idea why mule soft web services consumer its not populating method name with parameter.

Thanks
Ishwar

Comment: Hi Ishwar, there is a separate 
*Software Quality Assurance & Testing* community at http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ that might be more suitable for your question... :)

Comment: Hi Ishwar, Can u share the wsdl u r using ? It could be because of SOAPAction not being defined in ur WSDL operation

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample as below and it is wokring as expected. I am not sure if you have selected the Operation in Web Service Component. Refer the following, hope this will work for you -

[Webservice Consumer Component Operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAd7V.png)

[DataMapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNq0Q.png)

```
    <flow name="muletestFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-variable variableName="first" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.first]" doc:name="first"/>
    <set-variable variableName="second" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.second]" doc:name="second"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0%output application/xml%namespace ns0 http://tempuri.org/---
    {
        ns0#Add: {
            ns0#intA: flowVars.first as :number
        ,   ns0#intB: flowVars.second as :number
        }
    }]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="Add" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
</flow>
```